# Flipping polygon around arbitrary axis in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, transform

I want to flip a vector polygon about an arbitrary axis. What I would like to do is select the polygon to flip, pick two points (A & B in image below) identifying the axis about which the flip will occur, and get a result that looks like the red-dashed polygon.

**What I have tried:** searching for 'Flip', 'Mirror', 'Transform' in QGIS processing tools and web searches.

As a workaround, I've been using the 'Shape Tools' plugin 'Flip Horiz/Vert' in combination with QGIS Vector Tools 'Rotate'.

[image: vector flip about arbitrary line]

Comment: Phew... I guess you need to create a line from your points, then extend it, then calculate the distance and direction of each polygon vertex to the line, then translate each vertex by that distance, and finally convert your vertices back to a line and that to a polygon. I doubt this is possible without creating a new layer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wrote this code that reflects a polygon between a line created by two points. I don't know the best way for you to input the feature and the points, so the implementation is very basic and you'll probably need to fix some lines for your main purpose.

*Note: I am not an expert mathematician nor a python programmer. Maybe this script is inefficient but the important thing is to get the idea.*

***Notes***

- This script is very basic, so it works only with single part polygon geometries.
- This code modifies and overrides the features geometries, so be careful
- This include snapping tools.

You only need to paste the code in the QGIS python console, then select the feature you want to reflect, run the code, left click first point of the reflection line right click second point of the reflection line.

```py
class MapTool(QgsMapToolCapture):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(iface.mapCanvas(), iface.cadDockWidget(), QgsMapToolCapture.CaptureLine)
        self.setAutoSnapEnabled(True)
        self.startCapturing()
        
    def cadCanvasPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == 1:
            if len(self.points()) == 3:
                self.undo()
        elif len(self.points()) == 2 and self.currentVectorLayer().selectedFeatureCount() == 1:
            self.reflect()
            
    def reflect(self):
        point_a, point_b = self.points()
        feature = next(self.currentVectorLayer().getSelectedFeatures())
        polygon = feature.geometry().asPolygon()[0]
        new_polygon = []
        try:
            m = (point_a.y() - point_b.y()) / (point_a.x() - point_b.x())
            b = point_a.y() - m * point_a.x()
            try:
                inv_m = -1 / m
                for x, y in polygon:
                    b_n = y - inv_m * x
                    l_x_coord = (b_n - b) / (m - inv_m)
                    l_y_coord = m * l_x_coord + b
                    new_x = 2 * l_x_coord - x
                    new_y = 2 * l_y_coord - y
                    new_polygon.append(QgsPointXY(new_x, new_y))
            except ZeroDivisionError:
                for x, y in polygon:
                    l_y_coord = points_a.y()
                    new_x = x
                    new_y = 2 * l_y_coord - y
                    new_polygon.append(QgsPointXY(new_x, new_y))
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            for x, y in polygon:
                l_x_coord = point_a.x()
                new_x = 2 * l_x_coord - x
                new_y = y
                new_polygon.append(QgsPointXY(new_x, new_y))
                
        self.currentVectorLayer().changeGeometry(feature.id(), QgsGeometry.fromPolygonXY([new_polygon]))

canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
if iface.activeLayer().type() == QgsMapLayerType.Vector:
    map_tool = MapTool()
    canvas.setMapTool(map_tool)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the ["Geometry Generator"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/style_library/symbol_selector.html#the-geometry-generator) to dynamically create a copy (visualization only) of your polygon, flipped around the line on the layer `axis` using the following expression. Whenever you change the line, the flipped polygon will adapt immediately:

```
make_polygon(
    make_line (
        array_foreach (
            generate_series (1,  num_points( $geometry)),
            with_variable (
                'line',
                make_line (
                    point_n( $geometry, @element),
                    closest_point( 
                        extend (
                            overlay_nearest(
                                'axis',  --change the name to the name of the line layer you use
                                $geometry
                            )[0], 
                            100000, -- adapt these distances on this and the next line (just needed in case the axis is shorter then the polygon)
                            100000
                        ),
                        point_n ($geometry, @element)
                    )
                ),
                end_point (
                    extend (@line,0,length(@line))
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

*Red: initial polygon, blue: flipped polygon; black: axis*
[image]

Answer (score 1):

For what it is worth, you can achieve a reflection by a series of other transformations.

In this case a rotation->scale->rotation. The scale uses an x-scale of -1 and y-scale of 1 - essentially a flip across the x-axis. All of these transformations use a centre point as the nearest point on the axis to the centre point of the bounding box of the geometry.

The main advantage of this is that you can reflect the entire geometry rather than doing it point by point.

In the expression below

- **axis** is the geometry of the axis
- **angle** is the angle of the axis (can be greater than 180 degrees)
- **abs_angle** is the angle of the axis - less than 180 degrees
- **bb_centroid** is the centroid of the bounding box
- **nearest_point** is the point on the axis closest to the centroid of the bounding box

You could build this into a custom function/expression (Reflect)!

```
with_variable('axis', aggregate('axis', 'array_agg', @geometry)[0],
with_variable('angle', line_interpolate_angle(@axis, length(@axis)/2),
with_variable('abs_angle', if(@angle > 180,@angle - 180, @angle),
with_variable('bb_centroid', centroid(bounds(@geometry)),
with_variable('nearest_point', closest_point(@axis, @bb_centroid),
rotate(scale(rotate(@geometry, -@abs_angle, @nearest_point), -1, 1, @nearest_point), @abs_angle, @nearest_point))))))
```

In the images below, there are two geometries being reflected. The black figures are the original ones, the green figures are the reflected, the grey dash line depicts the bounding box, the red dot depicts the centre of the bounding box of the original figure and the yellow dot the centre of rotation/scaling.

[image]

[image]

[image]